# How can I set the title on a GWT cell widget?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have a cell table that has several columns whose data may occasionally be wider than their column's width.

I have my css text-overflow set to ellipsis so it is obvious to the user that there is more to the cell's value when it exceeds the column's width.

With a "normal" widget, I would just use setTitle() to automatically display the full contents on mouse over, but the TextCell (and all other cell widgets) do not extend UiObject, so they do not have this method available.

A TextCell is implemented by a div within a td tag. Being able to set the title on either elements would give me the behavior I am looking for, but I cannot seem to find a way to get a handle on either of the elements.

What is the best way to get the HTML title behavior to work in a cell table widget?

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write your own cell implementation and set the title in the html template yourself.

Take a look at a cell implementation. Basically they provide the html string for rendering.

Comment: I created a widget that extends the TextCell and overrides the render method to add a wrapping div tag whose title I could set. Not sure this is the most elegant solution...

Comment: 'code' public class TitledTextCell extends TextCell {

 public TitledTextCell() {
  super();
 }

 @Override
 public void render(Context context,
   SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
     if (value != null) {
      // create yet another div so that we may set it's title
      sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div title=\"" + value.asString() + "\">");
         sb.append(value);
      sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
       }
 }

}

Comment: its not the most elegant, but its okay. You could take a look inside TextCell and change the template to include your title directly (you would save one div)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a great idea. Where in the namespace do I look for the template?

Comment: I need the same, just: <td title="blabla">bla</td> - Surprisingly there is no such method in com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell(AbstractCell) API, I don't understand why? (

Answer (score 0):

Some of these kinds of issues have been "fixed" in GWT 2.3. But if you are stuck with using GWT 2.2, then writing your own cell implementation is the way to go.

Comment: I am using 2.3, I just am a n00b here so could not create my own tag for 2.3

Comment: no title in 2.3 table cell (e.g. com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractCell<C>)